# Spin button min value 001?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to enumerate some items from 001 to 999
Maybe, if I could set a spinButton like this

```
spin1.Min = 001
spin1.Max = 999
```

But Excel does not accept such min value?
How can I do this, pls ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set min/max to 1/999 integer then handle the values as text

if [A1] = 1 then in Excel

`=TEXT(A1,"000")`

or in VBA use

`Format(val, "000")`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using 1 instead of 001? Typically 001 is considered a string not a numeric value.

Comment: @ datatoo, I have over 10.000 items and only 3 numeric places to tagged them. It seems ooo's idea will be near the solution.

Comment: Have you concluded that 001, 01, and 1 are all separate values the spinner is using? Or you realize they all represent the same value? Was not clear that you are getting these values externally, only that you wanted the spinner to work, and why it wasn't